# Reverse proxy support in Quarkus

Tags: reverse-proxy, quarkus, undertow

I have Embedded Jetty running which has reverse proxy servlet mapped for a particular URL. For ex: http://url1/abc is reverse proxied to http://url2. This works great, whenever someone calls http://url1/abc, data is served from http://url2.

I want to achieve the same using quarkus. Is this possible to do it in Quarkus? I think one of the option is to write own code in ContainerRequestFilter but I am looking more for OOTB support just like jetty. Can somehow undertow be leveraged here?

Please help.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried to do it through undertow-handlers.conf (placing it in META-INF folder). It worked well for redirect and rewrite but throwing error for reverse-proxy:

```
path-prefix('/a') -> redirect('/b)
path-prefix('/a1') -> rewrite('/b1')
path-prefix('/a2') -> reverse-proxy('http://localhost:7100/b')
```

If I have first two only, quarkus is started successfully and requests are served correctly. If I started using third one, quarkus start gets failed with below error.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000045: Error parsing predicated handler string no handler named reverse-proxy known handlers are [disallowed-methods, allowed-methods, jdbc-access-log, secure-cookie, access-log, mark-secure, response-rate-limit, canonical-path, response-code, disable-cache, ssl-headers, trace, blocking, url-decoding, access-control, redirect, set, ip-access-control, request-limit, resource, restart, clear, byte-range, done, rewrite, forwarded, stuck-thread-detector, jvm-route, learning-push, dump-request, proxy-peer-address, resolve-local-name, header, store-response, path-separator, resolve-peer-name]:

Although, I see undertow has reverse-proxy handler, not sure why it is not working for me.
http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/index.html#predicates-attributes-and-handlers

I think the main issue is of dependency here. I see io\undertow\server\handlers package in my app libs but not io\undertow\server\handlers\proxy where I think the reverse proxy code is present.

How can I pull this dependency in my app?

Comment: As discussed over quarkus google groups, undertow reverse proxy module is not yet included in quarkus.